# Using trigonometric identities to prove following equation...

Tags: trigonometry

I'm stuck on this problem:

> If
>   $$a\sin^2x + b\cos^2x = c$$ 
>   $$b\sin^2y + a\cos^2y = d$$
>   $$a\tan x=b\tan y$$
>   then prove that
>   $$\frac{a^2}{b^2} = \frac{(d-a)(c-a)}{(b-c)(b-d)}$$

Comment: Tried to find out $\frac{a}{b} sin^2x$ and $\frac{a}{b} cos^2x$ then add them and square them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$${{a^2}\over{b^2}}={{\tan^2y}\over{\tan^2x}}={{\sin^2y\cos^2x}\over{\cos^2y\sin^2x}}$$
also
$$\cos^2x={{c-a}\over{b-a}}$$
$$\sin^2x={{c-b}\over{a-b}}$$
$$\cos^2y={{d-b}\over{a-b}}$$
$$\sin^2y={{d-a}\over{b-a}}$$

Therefore the result can easily be derived.

$${{a^2}\over{b^2}}={{(d-a)(c-a)(a-b)(a-b)}\over{(b-a)(b-a)(c-b)(d-b)}}$$

Comment: But, how did you find out the values of $cos^2x$ , $cos^2y$, $sin^2x$ and $sin^2y$?

Comment: @LeConnoisseur Replace for instance in the first equation $\cos^2 x$ with $1-\sin^2 x$. Of course, all of this won't work if any of the denominators is zero.

Comment: Even so it's still correct and ambiguous and results no information. Any way I don't think the problem considers such special cases.........

Comment: Yeah, its pretty much a general case problem. I guess it can't be solved without such assumptions. @Jean-ClaudeArbaut , got it!

Answer (score -1):

I think it's wrong.

Try $a=b=c=d=x=y=1.$